# Google map markers' information in Jade

Tags: javascript, mongodb, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, pug

I am quite new to programming so my question may sound very basic but I am trying to make this page in which the map is shown with the markers loaded from database (MongoDB) and by clicking on the markers the associated attributes (like the body of the post, the author, the date of the post being posted and the title of the post) will appear in a division. I managed to load the markers, make the division appear and disappear but I don't know what is the best approach to link the marker's data to the division content. mainly my question is how make it in a way that when a user choose a marker (location) the relevant posts to that location will appear. I tried to pass those information as a marker's attribute but I didn't succeed. Here are my codes:

this is my app.js code:

```
var getlat = require ("./public/assets/js/data.js");
app.get('/here', function(req, res){

  getlat(function(err, latlng, id, text, date, category, feeling, hashtag, author){
    if(err){
      return res.send(500);
    } 
    console.log("loading points");
    res.render('samples', {
        latlng: latlng,
        id: id,
        category: category,
        feeling: feeling,
        hashtag: hashtag,
        author: author,
        text: text,
    });
   });
});
```

This is my map code:

```
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.467216, -2.233701),
        zoom: 15,
    });

    var markers = [];
    var loc = !{
        JSON.stringify(latlng)
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < loc.length; i++) {
        var mylocation = loc[i];
        var lat = mylocation.replace(/^\"\(([0-9-.]*),.*/g, "$1");
        var lng = mylocation.replace(/.*,\s*([0-9-.]*)\)\"$/g, "$1");
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (marker) {
            if ($('#story').css('display') == 'block') {
                $('#story').css('display', 'none');
                return
            } else {
                $('#story').css('display', 'block');
            }
        });
        markers.push(marker);
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

and my jade body code:

```
  #map-canvas
  - for (var i = 0; i < id.length; ++i) {          
  br
  div(id='story' class='story' style='display: none;') 
    a(style='color: #21610B; font-weight: bold; font-family: \'Abril+Fatface\', serif; font-size:20px;')= hashtag[i]
```

Thanks alot

Comment: What didn't work when passing the info as a marker attribute? You are pushing the marker to a markers array. That should work.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. When I add them as a marker attribute it doesn't show the markers anymore. Maybe I am defining marker attributes wrong!

Comment: Make sure you don't use an existing attribute. What did you use? You could try with something like `marker.myData`, `marker.myAuthor`, etc.

Comment: I tried to put them inside var marker= new google.maps.Marker({...}). I think that's my mistake! should I define them outside the google map marker and inside the loop?!

Comment: What variable holds your data? `loc` and `mylocation` within the loop?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally found the solution now it's working fine! :) I just tried using the variable in just alerting them and it's working! :)
      var markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: latLng,
      customInfo: story,
      mytitle: titles
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(markerA, 'click', function() {
      alert(this.customInfo + this.mytitle);
      });

Comment: Yup, that's how I'd do it. You are welcome.